# Oracle Making local tables using dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, dynamic-sql

How to use local temporary table or alternative using dynamic SQL in Oracle?

In SQL Server, to select all the columns from a table called dbo.2019 into a local temporary table called x:

```
CREATE TABLE #x (a int)

DECLARE @FY varchar(4) = Year(date())

EXEC ('SELECT * into #x FROM dbo.'+@FY)
```

The reason why I want to do this is because I want to use all kinds of information (besides year, like values from other tables or whatever) to build very complicated queries in a manner that does not require lots of bizarre subqueries.

The limitation of SQL Server is that you must make your temporary tables first, or you have to use global ones, that people could write over.

Comment: Just a thought, and am not good with sql-server, but why cant you use CTE. https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/

Comment: On the last version I used in Oracle, there were no temp tables as in SQL Server. Temp tables in Oracle were permanent tables that would store data temporarily. Similar to having a table data type.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Oracle <> MS SQL Server. The latter uses temporary tables a lot. Oracle - usually/mostly - doesn't need them.

But, for your specific problem ("very complicated queries" and stuff), that maybe isn't a bad idea. Depending on your Oracle database version, there are **global temporary tables** (and - in most recent versions, **private** ones). How do they work? You create them once and use many times, which means that you should NOT create them dynamically. Data stored within is visible to you only, although many users can use it simultaneously. Furthermore, data is kept during the whole session (if you opt to create them with the `on commit preserve rows` option) or during transaction (`on commit delete rows`).

For example:

```
SQL> create global temporary table gtt_test
  2    (id     number,
  3     name   varchar2(20))
  4  on commit delete rows;

Table created.

SQL>
```

You can index them:

```
SQL> create index i1_gtt on gtt_test (id);

Index created.

SQL>
```

and do anything you want. Once your session (or transaction) is over, puff! they are empty, not data is permanently stored within. When you have to do the same job tomorrow, the table is still here, waiting for you. No *dynamic* create/drop/create/drop (or whatever you thought you should do).

So: create it once, use it any time you need.

---

If it **must** be dynamically, beware of this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    -- check whether table already exists
  5    select count(*)
  6      into l_Cnt
  7      from user_tables
  8      where table_name = 'TEST';
  9
 10    -- yes, it exists - drop it first
 11    if l_cnt = 1 then
 12       execute immediate 'drop table test';
 13    end if;
 14    -- now create it
 15    execute immediate 'create table test (id number, name varchar2(20))';
 16
 17    -- insert some rows
 18    insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Littlefoot');
 19  end;
 20  /
  insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Littlefoot');
              *
ERROR at line 18:
ORA-06550: line 18, column 15:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 18, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


SQL>
```

Although I'm first checking whether the table exists (so that I'd drop it first and then recreate it), the whole PL/SQL block failed because I'm trying to use a table that doesn't exist yet (at compile time).

So, if I'd want to use that `test` table, any operation - within the same PL/SQL block - should also become dynamic, and that's *horrible*: ugly to write, difficult to debug, beware of single quote problems ... you'd really want to avoid that.

---

Once again: I'd suggest you not to do that dynamically.